# How to obtain all Facebook friends in Android

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-android-sdk, facebook-sdk-3.1, facebook-friends

I'm trying to obtain a list of Facebook friends and to put it in a ListView on an Android app. Could you give me a hint or example of how to do this? I'm new in using Facebook SDK for Android and I don't know how to start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can no longer get the full list of friends for a user.  You can only get the list of friends who have also accepted the app.  You can get additionally ask for Invitable Friends to see which friends you might invite to also use the app.  But just getting a full list is no longer possible.  Please see https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/upgrading#upgrading_v2_0_user_ids for more information.